# sed match pattern and print two lines before pattern and all lines upto end of file

Tags: awk, sed

sample

```
tyu
abc

def
ghi
fgg
yui
```

Output

```
abc

def
ghi
fgg
yui
```

Matching pattern : `^def`
Print two lines before matching line including pattern and print all lines after pattern until end

Comment: Good that you have posted your used regex, please do add your complete tried code, else you may get close vote to your question. Thank you. NOTE: Efforts in form of regex is there, sharing your tried code(there is NO right or wrong in it) makes question more elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples try following `awk` code, written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)def.*' '
RT{
  num=split($0,arr,ORS)
  sub(/\n$/,"",RT)
  print arr[num-1] ORS arr[num]  RT
}
' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution(More Generic one):*** In this solution one could mention number of lines needed to be printed before a match is found in `awk`'s variable named `lines` and we need NOT to hardcode number of times we need to print array's element(in `split` function for first line).

```
awk -v lines="2" -v RS='(^|\n)def.*' '
RT{
  val=""
  num=split($0,arr,ORS)
  sub(/\n$/,"",RT)
  for(i=lines;i<=num;i++){
    val=(val?val ORS:"") arr[i]
  }
  print val RT
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk '
    f {print; next}                     # if the flag f is set, print the line
    {que[NR % 3] = $0}                  # store the line in a queue
    /^def/ {                            # if the pattern matches
        f = 1                           # then set the flag
        for (i = NR - 2; i <= NR; i++)  # and print two previous lines and current line
            print que[i % 3]
    }
' input_file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1N;N;/def/!D;:a;n;ba' file
```

Open a window of 3 lines and if the desired string is not present, delete the first and append another until a match is found.

Then print those lines and all other lines to the end of the file.

N.B. This will start printing as soon a match is found, even if the match is in the first or second lines. If the match must be in the third or subsequent lines, use:

```
sed '1N;N;/def[^\n]*$/!D;:a;n;ba' file
```